# Analyze HTTPS encrypted URL

Tags: https, cryptography, ssl-certificate

I have a URL with static content. Will i get same or different encrypted URL pattern on hitting the same url multiple times with HTTPs? Suggest me with tool to analyse the encrypted URL.

```
when we use https.........for example to send login credentials(https://example.com?username=aaaa&password=aaaa123). HTTPS encrypts the data using SSL certificate. So the url will be encrypted string. I am giving two requests with the same url(https://example.com?username=aaaa&password=aaaa123). On every request the url will be encrypted. Will the encrypted url of the first request be same as the encrypted url of the second request? Is the SSL certificate going to be different everytime btween client and server?
```

Thanks,
Iqbal

Comment: I don't understand what the URL and transport scheme (https) have to do with each other? The URL is defined by the application.

Comment: If you "hit the same URL" multiple times, it will be the *same* URL. What do you mean exactly? Are you referring to the same *content*?

Comment: Hi Duncan, After the url is encrypted, will it have the same encrypted pattern with the same key as before?

Comment: Hi....
 when we use https.........for example to send login credentials(https://example.com?username=aaaa&password=aaaa123). HTTPS encrypts the data using SSL certificate. So the url will be encrypted string. I am giving two requests with the same url(https://example.com?username=aaaa&password=aaaa123). On every request the url will be encrypted. Will the encrypted url of the first request be same as the encrypted url of the second request? Is the SSL certificate going to be different everytime btween client and server?

Thanks,
Iqbal